# button click event on update panel not firing in multiple user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am having an update panel which user control in it

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
         <uc1:SelectionAjax ID="SelectionAjax1" runat="server" />
         <ppmp:PinPadModal ID="ppmodal" runat="server" />
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and inside this user control I am calling  another two user controls each user control which has its own update panel

```
// First User Control
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpP1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFinalConfirmation" EventName="Click" /> 
            </Triggers>
       <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnFinalConfirmation" runat="server" Text="Confirm"  OnClick="btnFinalConfirmation_Click1" />
       </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>

//Second User Control
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmation" runat="server" Text="Confirm"  OnClick="btnConfirmation_Click1" />
           </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The issue is that button click event is only being fired on the second user control not the first one how should I solve this

Answer (score 0):

Include **ScriptManager** in your Aspx Page.This **ScriptManager** control provides support for client-side AJAX features in an AJAX enabled web pages.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help but this is already added in the page but still not working

Comment: Your trigger is inside the content template.That's mean the main page is contain one user control it's placed inside the content template so already your user control include trigger method.put your user control outside the update panel.Then check it.